# How to fetch already purchased details of iOS IAP Auto Renewable product

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit, auto-renewable

I have created Auto renewable products and testing in sandbox environment. My question is  I have purchased one product, and If I try to purchase same product with same Apple account it is showing alert as already purchased as expected but I could not able to fetch that transaction details as it is executing failed state  in updated transactions.  How I can get that  purchased details (atleast original receiptID) as we get in Initial transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to get user **purchased transaction** details:

1. **Refresh receipt**
2. **Restore completed transaction**

To know more about difference between refreshing receipt & restore transaction in details, Please check:- [SKReceiptRefreshRequest vs restoreCompletedTransactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897238/skreceiptrefreshrequest-vs-restorecompletedtransactions/41032497#41032497)

In Simply,

- Refreshing the receipt asks the App Store for the latest copy of the receipt.
- Restoring completed transactions creates a new transaction for every completed transaction the user made, essentially replaying history for your transaction queue observer.

**Question:** 
How I can get that purchased details (atleast original receiptID) as we get in Initial transaction.

**Answer:** If you want to verify user with original receiptID every time each time than user SKReceiptRefreshRequest for validating user transaction.

**Note:** Anytime if you validating user with RestoreCompletedTransactions, Your transactionID will change. 
Find list of parameter that change while restoreTransaction: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a mechanism of restoring the purchased products in your app.

For more info about what exactly is restoring purchased products:
[Restore Purchased Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

To get to the implementation part, you can follow this tutorial:
[In App Purchase tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)

The later part of the tutorial will guide you through the implementaiton of restore purchase.

Answer (score 0):

By [validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) you can able to find which products identifiers are already purchased. There are Cocoapods libraries you can use to find out the purchased products.

1. [SwiftyStoreKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyStoreKit)
2. DHAppleReceiptParser
3. IAPValidation

I hope it will helps to you.